# how to read specific line in c# asp.net with closed xml

Tags: c#, asp.net

well, for example, i have a excel file with one value in the line A12, the value is "foobar", how to get the value "foobar" in line A12 with closed xml?

Thank

Comment: `closed xml` what is that? How is it related to excel?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya,closed XML is a free library to read/write excel file .. [Learn more about it](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

Comment: @zackraiyan yeah, this is, i see examples with XLWorkbook, but, need of several files, for example. XLFill, XLStyle and more others... is necessary?

Comment: WHy go with `closedXML` when u can get the job done by `DataTable` or even `DataReader` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, all libraries(almost) have well documentation but there are billions of ways to make use of one library which can't be predicted neither can be documented .. Hope u understand :)

Comment: @zackraiyan cause i get this data in excel file and need pass for sql

Comment: Never used `ClosedXML` personally but u can always use a datareader or a datatable, go with an one of these , do u want me to post an answer ?

Comment: Zack, thank u for answer,for contribution, but i need use Closed XML

Comment: Maybe try having a look at the [ClosedXML examples](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/tree/develop/ClosedXML_Examples) of their git, or at the [ClosedXML Wiki](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this, below are the 2 most common ones I use:

```
var path = @"pathtoworkbook.xlsx";

// Load workbook from specified path.
var wb = new XLWorkbook(path);

// Get the first worksheet in the workbook.
var ws = wb.Worksheet(1);

// Returns "foobar"
var a12Value = ws.Row(12).Cell(1).GetString();

// Returns "foobar"
var a12Value1 = ws.Cell("A12").GetString();
```

The first goes to row 12 and gets the first cell.

The second goes straight to the desired cell address.

Comment: everything, tell for me open a file and search the file "XLWorkbook.cs" when arrives in var wb = new XLWorkbook(path);

Comment: Not sure I'm following the question. The XLWorkbook constructor can take a string which is the path to the .xlsx file to open.